# How are we typedef-ing the same struct with two different pointers? And what does the term_t do?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

```
struct term{ 
    double coef; 
    unsigned deg; 
    struct term * next;
}term_t;
typedef struct term * Term; 
typedef struct term * Poly;
```

I have to use this code for a class of Polynomials. This code was provided by my professor, but I don't understand why it works.

Comment: This doesn't "work" as-is. (Not to mention that it has undefined behavior because of the `_t` suffix which is reserved for the implementation.) This is a data structure. You'll need an algorithm to decide whether or not it works. I also don't understand what your problem is - this is syntactically (and so far semantically, but there's really not much semantics in there) correct C code (apart from the picky UB which rarely, if ever, causes problems).

Comment: @Mat Oh, is it only POSIX then?

Comment: @H2CO3: ah yes thanks, that's in POSIX. Cool, wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct term
{ 
    double coef; 
    unsigned deg; 
    struct term * next;
} term_t;
```

This is defining `struct term` and `typedef`ing it to `term_t` at the same time.  `term_t` is acting like an alias for `struct term` so that you can create a struct variable of this type by simply including this line...

```
term_t termVar;
```

...instead of having to use this line...

`struct term termVar;`

```
typedef struct term * Term; 
typedef struct term * Poly;
```

These lines are creating an alias for `struct term *`.  Now you can use lines like...

```
Term pTermVar;
```

...instead of...

```
struct term *pTermVar;
```

They could have also been `typedef`ed like this:

```
typedef term_t * Term;
typedef Term Poly;
```

Comment: so does that mean that Term and Poly would mean the same thing?

Comment: @user3079315 That is correct.